# div won't touch other elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate the FreeBSD website. I have tried using vertical-align, display, position and a CSS reset. I am not allowed to float anything in this exercise, either. For some reason the div "center" won't touch the image or the div "textAndForm" or the top of the page.

```
<div id="container">
      <img src="FreeBSDlogo.png">
      <div id="center">
         <h1>The power to serve</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="textAndForm">
         <p>Text Size: </span class="goldLinks">Normal</span> / </span class="goldLinks">Large</span> | </span class="goldLinks">Donate</span> | </span class="goldLinks">Contact</span>
                <br/>
         <label>
            <input type="text" name="Search">
         </label>
                <br/>
         <input type="submit" value="Search">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for `margin` and `padding` settings. I can't see your CSS, but browser elements come with some default `margin` and `padding` options. Setting these to `0` on the appropriate elements should do the trick.